# Создать фильтр-тест для товаров

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно создать фильтр-тест для товаров, есть 3 категории и 3 значения, в итоге 27 значений в зависимости от конфигураций. На каждое из значений есть отдельная ссылка, на которую попадаешь после нажатия кнопки.

[image: как это выглядит]

Менять значения в тесте можно в любом порядке и несколько раз и ссылка от корректно этого меняется... пока вообще ничего не нашла, в js не сильна

Comment: Ответ ниже мне помог понять как приписывать значение, а как прописывать ссылку и задать каждой определенное значение этих категорий, чтобы для каждой комбинации ссылка была разной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

Три скрытых поля:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="category1_value" name="category1_value" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="category2_value" name="category2_value" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="category3_value" name="category3_value"/>
    <input type="button" value="Перейти к ссылке" onclick="loadFilterPage()" />
</form>
```

У Ваших 9 блоков будет свойство `onclick`:

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('category1_value').value='1'"></div>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('category1_value').value='2'"></div>
...
<div onclick="document.getElementById('category3_value').value='8'"></div>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('category3_value').value='9'"></div>
```

И добавить скрипт:

```
<script>
function loadFilterPage(){
    // Получаем значения скрытых полей:
    var cat1value = document.getElementById('category1_value').value;
    var cat2value = document.getElementById('category2_value').value;
    var cat3value = document.getElementById('category3_value').value;
    // Объединяем их в строку:
    var catsStr = cat1value + "," + cat2value + "," + cat3value;
    // В зависимости от строки формируем ссылку:
    var pageHref;
    switch(catsStr) {
        case '1,1,1': pageHref = "1.html"; break;
        case '1,1,2': pageHref = "2.html"; break;
        case '1,1,3': pageHref = "3.html"; break;
        ...
        case '3,3,2': pageHref = "26.html"; break;
        case '3,3,3': pageHref = "27.html"; break;
        default: alert('Неверное значение'); break;
    }
    // переходим по найденной ссылке:
    if(pageHref != ''){ setTimeout('location.replace("'+pageHref+'")', 0); }
}
</script>
```

а вообще странно, по идее должна быть одна страница типа page.php, она загружается по отправке формы, там в _POST получаете значения полей и загружаете нужный контент. Но если нужно разные ссылки - код выше.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! А как прописывать ссылку и задать каждой определенное значение этих категорий?

Comment: @ev.zdanovich Подскажите, у Вас 27 разных страниц (вида /1.html, 2.html и так далее) или одна страница вида "1.html", которая должна по-разному отображаться в зависимости от фильтров? Я дополню ответ тогда.

Comment: Это все разные страницы (1.html, 2.html и так далее)

Comment: Дополнил ответ. При нажатии на кнопку должен скрипт переходить по одной из ссылок. И немного изменил старые блоки, исправьте их тоже в Вашем коде. А вообще, конечно, зря я все это писал. Тут желательно выкладывать Ваш код, и что не получается. Если ответ помог, нажмите там "принять" хоть =)

Comment: Cсылки не работают почему-то. но дефолтное значение срабатывает. Спасибо вам большое, я только начинаю изучать JS

Comment: А можете дать ссылку, где это должно работать? посмотрим, что не так. По идее, я брал с моего кода, все рабочее должно быть.

Comment: http://www.mothercare.ru/ru/testtesttest.html и вот здесь

Comment: Простите, это я ошибся, надо строчку последнюю исправить так: `if(pageHref != ''){ setTimeout('location.replace("'+pageHref+'")', 30); }`

Comment: урааа! супер! я ваша должница! Спасибо огромное! Вы просто герой! все работает, даже лучше чем хотелось

Comment: @ev.zdanovich Не за что =) Рад, что заработало =) Отметьте ответ галочкой, если не сложно =)