# Взятие элемента из таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

Как взять значение из ячейки и подставить его в ссылку? Есть таблица

```
    <table id="history">
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="nyr">ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">1</td>
            <td class="cell">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">3</td>
            <td class="cell">4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Как например кликнуть по 4му элементу и его содержимое подставить в ссылку? 
Есть наработка, но не знаю в правильном направлении

```
http://..../users/del/?id=" + document.getElementById('history').rows[i].cells[i].innerHTML
```

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдет то, что тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751735/Создать-фильтр-тест-для-товаров/751752#751752 там правда кликать не по таблице, а по дивам, но суть, наверное, та же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно передавая `this` ссылку в саму функцию. В `href1` в данном решении храню саму ссылку. Такой способ удобнее, чем заранее хранить массив ссылок, так как все данные хранятся сразу в ячейке.

```js
function setHref(ell){
  var a = document.getElementById('myHref');
  var val = ell.innerHTML;
  var link = ell.getAttribute("href1");
  a.innerHTML = val;
  a.setAttribute('href', link);
}
```

```html
<table id="history">
  <tr class="row">
    <th class="nyr">ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell" href1="link1" onclick="setHref(this)">1</td>
    <td class="cell" href1="link2" onclick="setHref(this)">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell" href1="link3" onclick="setHref(this)">3</td>
    <td class="cell" href1="link4" onclick="setHref(this)">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a id="myHref" href="/myPage">ссылка</a>
```

В данном примере можно и просто `href` написать вместо `href1`, у себя в коде я бы так и сделал, написал `href1` для ясности для новичков, что это мой кастомный аттрибут.

Comment: Вообще не пойму, чем это от моего ответа отличается...

Comment: @Максим Степанов отличая два, как раз поэтому и написал ответ. 1. Что ссылка передаётся через атрибуты. 2. вызов функции идёт через функцию без передачи внешних параметров, только this. Да и я свой ответ написал на основе вашего, поэтому спасибо и ставлю вашему ответу лайк. Прошу также если вы ставили дизвоут мне, убрать его.

Comment: я вижу отличия, только не понимаю, в чем их суть. Дизвоут правда поставил я. Уберу, конечно, но все-таки не понимаю, какой смысл в изменениях. Почему бы в данном случае не передавать ссылку через параметром? Универсальной функция все равно не будет, потому что внутри `getElementById`, читаемость кода одинаковая, в чем идея не пойму?

Comment: через 3 часа поставлю обратно, сейчас не дают мне это сделать (

Comment: @Максим Степанов привило. KISS Keep it as simple as possible. В данном случае лучше использовать меньше передаваемых параметров при возможности. Более конкретно если этот код генерирует серверный движок, то в случае что вы предложили на каждую клетку надо отдельную функцию сгенерировать, а в случае с this функция одна и таже. Опять принцип KISS.

Comment: спасибо, не знал. Я почему-то думал, что неважно, что передавать функции,  объект this или строку-ссылку. Думал - они же все равно разные, а функция одна. Вы не могли бы чуть поправить ответ, я не могу голос вернуть, пока ответ не отредактирован....

Comment: @Максим Степанов поправил. Как я понимаю что бы вернуть голос надо на кнопку которую нажимали и щёлкнуть ещё раз. То есть ещё раз вниз щёлкнуть.

Comment: пробовал и вниз и вверх, не выходило =). Вот сейчас сработало.

Comment: @Максим Степанов Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

По клику вставить в ссылку можно, например, так:

```js
function setHref(iValue){
  var a = document.getElementById('myHref');
  a.innerHTML = 'ссылка_id_'+iValue;
  a.setAttribute('href', '/myPage?id='+iValue);
}
```

```html
<table id="history">
  <tr class="row">
    <th class="nyr">ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell" onclick="setHref(1)">1</td>
    <td class="cell" onclick="setHref(2)">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell" onclick="setHref(3)">3</td>
    <td class="cell" onclick="setHref(4)">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a id="myHref" href="/myPage">ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

правильно мыслите, меняйте j, i  и смотрите ячейки таблицы

```js
var j = 2;
var i = 0;

alert("http://..../users/del/?id=" + document.getElementById('history').rows[j].cells[i].innerHTML);
```

```html
 <table id="history">
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="nyr">ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">1</td>
            <td class="cell">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">3</td>
            <td class="cell">4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

а теперь генерируем ссылку в зависимости от нажатия на ячейку таблицы:

```js
function urlgen(){
  alert("http://..../users/del/?id=" + event.target.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table onclick=urlgen() id="history">
        <tr  class="row">
            <th class="nyr">ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">1</td>
            <td class="cell">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">3</td>
            <td class="cell">4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Я понял это. К примеру, если я кликну на второй ячейки, где лежит 2, если будут   `var j = 2; var i = 0;` подставиться в ссылку цифра 4, а не 2. Как сделать это?

Comment: тогда всё ещё проще, дополнил ответ